# How to make an "out-of-date" notification for a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, notifications

I'm something of a MySQL newbie, and I was wondering if there was any way to set up a notification system so that an e-mail notification would be sent any time an entry hasn't been updated for a specific amount of time (say, 6 months). Preferably, it would be done by specific category rather than row. Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a field storing the timestamp of the last update, and run daily job (very very small script)